Split dataframe output, but keep rows with the same value in a column in the same split
I have the following dataframe which I want to split into three separate Excel sheets each containing three rows:



Group
Amount




1
247


1
194


2
901


2
111


2
781


3
610


4
591


4
220


4
481


5
421


5
430


5
449



Using an answer found in Splitting a Dataframe into multiple sheets, the following code successfully splits the code equally into threes across multiple sheets:
GROUP_LENGTH = 3
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('TestDataFrame.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
number_of_chunks = math.ceil(len(test_data)/GROUP_LENGTH)
chunks = np.array_split(test_data, number_of_chunks)
sheet_number = 0
for chunk in chunks:
    chunk.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=f'3 Lines Sheet Number {sheet_number}')
    sheet_number+=1
writer.close()

However, I would like to group rows that have the same 'Group' column value so that they end up on the same sheet. Effectively, the code should split into threes as far as possible, but take into account the 'Group' column value so that they don't get split: Desired output is:
Sheet 1



Group
Amount




1
247


1
194


2
901


2
111


2
781



Sheet 2



Group
Amount




3
610


4
591


4
220


4
481



Sheet 3



Group
Amount




5
421


5
430


5
449




If you have 4 different group numbers, why do you only want 3 groups? and why are you separating the #2 group into sheet 1 and 2?

@iBeMeltin I've updated the example, there was an error so it should be clearer now. My logic is sort of, when you get to the row split limit, keep going until you hit a row with a different Group value, then split it, to ensure each file has a complete group together.
